# Which is faster between Linq to Sql And SQl Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have List of object like this

```
List<Product> _products;
```

Then I get productId input and search in this list like this

```
var target = _peoducts.Where(o => o.productid == input).FirstOrDefault();
```

my Question is

1. If This list have 100 Products  (productId from 1 to 100) and an
   input I get productId = 100. that mean this Method must loop for 100
   time Right ? (If I `ORDER BY productId ASC` in Query)
2. Between use this Method and Query on Database with where clause like
       this `WHERE productId = @param`

Thank you.

Comment: If you have a `List<Product>` to execute that `Where` on, it's not linq-to-sql (or entity framework), but plain linq-to-objects.

Comment: ... which is much slower in this case

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 1):

1. No. If there is an index with key `productId` it finds the correct row with O(log n) operations
2. Just implement both methods and take the time. (hint: use `StopWatch()` class)

---

**Edit**

To get the full performance you should **not** create an intermediate (unsorted) `List<T>` but put all your logic in a LINQ query which operates on the SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

@might be helpful to get your answer.

https://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you execute that `Where` on a `List<Product>`, then:

- you got all 100 rows from the database
- and then looped through all products in memory until you found the one that matches or until you went through the entire list and found nothing.

If, on the other hand, you used an `IQueryable<Product>` that was connected to the database table, then:

- You wouldn't have read anything from the database yet
- When you apply the `Where`, you still wouldn't read anything
- When you apply the `FirstOrDefault` a sql query is constructed to find just the one row you need. Given correct indexes on the table, this would be quite fast.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your response in this case it's a Linq to Object then it's not search with index on table right ?

Comment: @ChanomFirst - no, those product objects are then already copied from the database into local memory (of the .Net process), so an index on the table will not help you.